# Orange box appeared around cursor Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Some combination of keys I hit caused this:
[image]

The box goes wherever the mouse goes. I was working and compiling a program, moving fast with the keyboard and this appeared. What? Now all I can do is obsess how to get rid of it. I can move around inside the box, but when the mouse wants to, so go right outside the box, the box will move to the right with the mouse cursor.


[image]

Comment: what's in your taskbar might have useful clues, as does whatever processes are running

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thank you for chiming in. I guess the compiler software caused something to "ghost" on my screen or captured remnants of a window in the background. Now that I wasted about 2 hours I finally restart my PC and it's gone. Dunno!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it must have been a glitch/bug caused when I recompiled my program. Something must have caused a remnant of a windows in the bacground, or captured the remnant of a background window, thus causing that "ghost outline".

**When in doubt REBOOT**. **Solved** this issue.

-- by OP